# Play Framework 2.4-M3: Issues with unit testing in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I'm running Play Framework 2.4-M3 with Java, and I'm trying to write a unit test that needs a running Application.  I am trying to get this to work with the following code:

```
Application app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build();

running(app, () -> {
    // Unit test code here
});
```

The problem that I'm running into is that `running`, as well as the other ways of doing this like `WithApplication`, require a play.Application.  However, `new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build()` is returning a play.api.Application and giving an incompatible type error.  I'm following the examples in the documentation, so I'm not sure why it's not working.  Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I just finally figured out what I did wrong.  I guess I accidentally had my IDE import the Scala version of GuiceApplicationBuilder instead of the Java version.  I didn't notice that until just now.  I changed it to the Java version, and now it's working.